# Error Initializing Elasticsearch (VM) - Too small initial heap

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm trying to initialize the Elasticsearch using this [init.d](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/rpm/init.d/elasticsearch) file, with the configurations below:

```
# Heap Size (defaults to 256m min, 1g max)
ES_HEAP_SIZE=1g

# Maximum number of open files
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
```

But after running the service I get the following error message:

`Error occurred during initialization of VM
Too small initial heap`

The server I'm using is a *m3.medium* from EC2, which haves 3.75g of memory

Comment: Are you seeing this in logs ? What is the ES and Java version

Comment: Just got this working, as soon as I can I'll post the answer myself

Comment: Who were you, @felipeclopes? What did you see?! https://xkcd.com/979/

(actually I'm not having this problem, just curious what happens if you set the heap too small)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer and now I don't know the solution anymore. I think it was related with the configuration file and the variable ES_HEAP_SIZE not being formatted properly. Instead of 'g', I defined it in 'm' (7168m).